# CSV File import to SQL Server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, csv

I am working for CSV File import to SQL Server

I got code from Internet ..working fine But when I am adding one extra field (User_Id) with that CSV file to SQL then this is giving error ....I am not able to understand where is doing mistake ....code...
                DataTable tblReadCSV = new DataTable();

```
            tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Name");
            tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Email");
            tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Mobile");

            tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("User_id");
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Email/UploadFile/" + path));
            path = Server.MapPath("~/Email/UploadFile/" + path);
            TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path);
             csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
            csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
            csvParser.ReadLine();

            while (!(csvParser.EndOfData == true))
            {
                tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields());
            }
            string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
            string strSql = "Insert into Contacts(Name,Email,Mobile,User_id ) values(@Name,@Email,@Mobile," + UserId +")";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strSql;
            cmd.Connection = con;               
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Name");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Email");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Mobile");

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_id", SqlDbType.Int , UserId);

            SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
            int result = dAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV);
            Label1.Text = "File successfully uploaded";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the error message is, nor where it occurs, but it seems to me that this line

```
string strSql = "Insert into Contacts(Name,Email,Mobile,User_id ) values(@Name,@Email,@Mobile," + UserId +")";
```

should probably be like this

```
string strSql = "Insert into Contacts(Name,Email,Mobile,User_id ) values(@Name,@Email,@Mobile,@User_id)";
```

Comment: but User_Id is local var for current user login ....I know that problem is in this field ....but how can I do that if i write @UserId then how can set current user value ?

Comment: @KrantiSingh - ok but you add it as a parameter to the query. So either change what I said or remove the line `cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_id", SqlDbType.Int , UserId)` - I can't see how it makes sense otherwise.

Comment: if it's a local variable then assign the variable and or capture it like you would any other variable / value .. local or not.. how are you capturing the current userId...? don't make the simple things so complicated..

Comment: I am not good in SQL ..  Thanks Friend for help ...I removed cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_id", SqlDbType.Int , UserId) and working fine ..thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
string strSql = "Insert into Contacts(Name,Email,Mobile,User_id)
values(@Name,@Email,@Mobile," + UserId +")";
```

with

```
string strSql = "Insert into Contacts(Name,Email,Mobile,User_id )
values(@Name,@Email,@Mobile,@UserId)";
```

In the above line, you are just declaring the parameters .

And this is how you actually pass the current user id:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_id", SqlDbType.Int , UserId);
```

Try this; hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

values(@Name,@Email,@Mobile," + UserId +")"// source from ur c

```
avoid ''+ UserId +'' in your string strSql..
```